# Selecting html select list from sql database

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I kind if have an interesting question. I'm trying to prefill an edit form in codeignitert. I have most of the values coming through the database, but my select box is giving me a few issues. I want it to only highlight what they had previously selected not erase the list and fill it in with what they selected...if that makes any sence.

Here is my html

```
<?foreach($info as $row) :?>
 <select multiple="multiple" class="multi" name="wGenre[]">
   <option value="Action/Adventure">Action/Adventure</option>
       <option value="Angst">Angst</option>
       <option value="Crime">Crime</option>
       <option value="Drama">Drama</option>
       <option value="Family">Family</option>
       <option value="Fantasy">Fantasy</option>
       <option value="Friendship">Friendship</option> 
       <option value="General">General</option>
  </select>
<?endforeach;?>
```

I've already tried a couple of things. I have tried putting the list in a inner for loop and trying to select what comes back through the echo, but that only threw me errors. I could do an individual if statement for each item, but I shortened the list above and have another just like it and that seems like an unnecessary amount of code.

If it helps, when I echo back the entire list it comes back as a string, like this. Fantasy Friendship General and I do have full text searching enabled.

Thank you in advance for any help! :)

Comment: can you elaborate what result you want and what you get

Comment: I would like to try to highlight what they had previously selected which is stored in the database. What I get back from the database when I echo out that value is the string I mentioned above "Fantasy Friendship General"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 <select multiple="multiple" class="multi" name="wGenre[]">
    <option value="Action/Adventure" <?php if(in_array('Action/Adventure',$info)) echo 'selected="selected"';?>>Action/Adventure</option>
```

Do the same for all

Comment: It's not coming back from the database as an array though, it's coming back as a string

Comment: just plain text like, Fantasy Friendship General

Comment: `$infoArray = explode(' ', $myString)` and then use `in_array` with the `$infoArray`. As an aside, this method prohibits you from having a category with spaces, since then when you encounter a space you don't know it it's part of category or a seperator for the next category. If you must store it in a string (which is debatable in the first place), better use something like commas to separate.

Comment: if all values are separated with white space than explode them with the space and assign it to $info.

Comment: you should get them comma separated from the mysql result.

Comment: Thank you so much ScallioXTX that did the trick! And thank you so much Manish Jangir for all you help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<select onchange="getwGenre(this.value);" name="wGenre" id="wGenre" >
 <?php  foreach( $info  as $row ) { 
    $sel = '';
   if( $row["wGenre_wGenre_name"] == $selected ) 
    $sel = 'selected="selected"';           

    echo '<option value="'.$row["wGenre_wGenre_name"].'" '.$sel.'>'.$row["wGenre_wGenre_name"].'</option>'."\n";
    } ?>
    </select>
    <?php echo form_error('wGenre'); ?>
```